# How is a mojolicious session token created?

Tags: perl, session-cookies, mojolicious

Are mojolicious session tokens created in a "standard" way (in a generic sense), or is this up to the individual application? If it is the former, then what is the format?

What I saw so far is a base64 encoded JSON fragment (which by itself is syntactically incomplete), followed by "---", followed by a random looking 40-digit hex-string.

I'm especially interested in the random looking token. Is it randomly generated, or is it the encoding/encryption of something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mojolicious session have base64 string (in the begin, first part) and sign (in the end, second part) which separated by "---". 
Sign is main part of session which prevent from changes.

So, make a test:

Add to session some value. Make request which get this value in the session.
Get session and transform first part of them (make base64_decode and change value then make base64_encode and put it before "--" in cookies).

Make query to server with new cookie/session. Your new data must be invalid in session.

So, sign it is IMPORTANT part of session.

Read [source code](https://metacpan.org/source/SRI/Mojolicious-5.49/lib/Mojolicious/Sessions.pm) to learn more about it

Read [this](https://metacpan.org/pod/Mojolicious#secrets) to know how to set secret key for sign cookies